# Python & Pandas. How to work with a subset of the "chunks" in a TextFileReader object?

Tags: python, pandas, import, chunks

I need to import a large `.txt` file (approx. 10GB) to do some calculations. I'm using Pandas in Python 2.7.

Basically, I need to construct sums and averages of certain series (columns), conditional on the value of other series. To be more precise: I have basic information on individuals living in a country, and, for example, I want to take the average age of the people in each municipality.

I cannot import the whole file (because it is too big), so I am doing it in "chunks" (using `read_table`, `chunksize`).
For each calculation, I don't need all of the chunks, just a subset of them.

Since the information might not be ordered, I first iterate over all chunks to identify which of them have information for each of the municipalities. Hence, for each municipality I have a list with the indices of the chunks that contain at least one observation belonging to it.

I would then like to use this list to select only those chunks, but I'm not being able to do it in a fast way.
The only thing that seems to work is to iterate over all chunks again.

Is there a way to directly select a subset of the "chunks" in a `TextFileReader` object without having to iterate over all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to do it this way:

```
res = \
pd.concat([df.assign(age=(pd.datetime.now() - df.dob).astype('m8[Y]').astype(int))
             .groupby(['country','municipality'])['age'].agg(['size','sum']).reset_index()
           for df in pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.txt', sep=..., chunksize=10**5) ],
          ignore_index=True)

res = res.groupby(['country','municipality'], as_index=False).sum()
```

This will give you a total number of individuals in each municipality (`size` column) and a sum of their ages (`sum` column).

`sum/size` - will give you an average age per municipality

**UPDATE:** you can use the following trick in order to calculate the age on the fly:

```
In [164]: df
Out[164]:
   country municipality        dob
0  Ukraine           m1 1950-01-01
1  Ukraine           m1 1960-12-14
2      USA           m2 1971-11-27
3      USA           m2 1982-11-09
4      USA           m3 1993-10-22
5  Germany           m1 2004-10-04
6  Germany           m2 2015-09-17

In [165]: df.assign(age=(pd.datetime.now() - df.dob).astype('m8[Y]').astype(int))
Out[165]:
   country municipality        dob  age
0  Ukraine           m1 1950-01-01   67
1  Ukraine           m1 1960-12-14   56
2      USA           m2 1971-11-27   45
3      USA           m2 1982-11-09   34
4      USA           m3 1993-10-22   23
5  Germany           m1 2004-10-04   12
6  Germany           m2 2015-09-17    1
```

**UPDATE2:** `pd.read_csv()` returns a `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader` instead of `DataFrame` as soon as you specify `chunksize`:

```
In [6]: reader = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\.data\1.csv', chunksize=3, sep='\s+')

In [7]: type(reader)
Out[7]: pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader
```

get 2 rows

```
In [12]: reader.get_chunk(2)
Out[12]:
      foo  foo.1   bar  bar.1  spam  spam.1
foo  0.00   0.35  0.83   0.84  0.90    0.89
foo  0.35   0.00  0.86   0.85  0.92    0.91
```

get next 3 rows

```
In [13]: reader.get_chunk(3)
Out[13]:
       foo  foo.1   bar  bar.1  spam  spam.1
bar   0.83   0.86  0.00   0.25  0.88    0.87
bar   0.84   0.85  0.25   0.00  0.82    0.86
spam  0.90   0.92  0.88   0.82  0.00    0.50
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MaxU for the answer. I believe this would work for the specific example I gave in the question. However, in some cases I have to treat the data before doing calculations, and I would like to know if it is possible to avoid iterating every time over all chunks. In particular, how would you modify the code if instead of having an ['age'] column, you had a ['date_of_birth'] column? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. I still don't know if it is possible to "select" certain chunks, but your solution is good, and it doesn't require to do it. If you happen to know, I would like how to use the `TextFileReader` object, because I'm clearly not getting exactly what it is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
for df1 in pd.read_csv('______.csv',chunksize=5):
    print(df1)
df
```